# how to use PHP to automatically delete from mysql at set date

Tags: mysql

I have added some rows into my ad table in the  database, their properties includes created date and expiry date.

I need php script to automatically delete the row that its expiry date has reached.

Pls assist my project.
Thanks u

Answer (score 4):

You could use MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html) to automatically delete such records when they expire:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_expired_101
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 WEEK DO
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 101;
```

Or to run an automatic purge of all expired records on a regular basis:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_all_expired
ON SCHEDULE EVERY HOUR DO
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE expiry < NOW();
```

Comment: The event schedule must be available on virtual host or web hosting

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $today = getdate();
   if($today <= $expirayDate)
   {
       //your deletion logic
   }
?>
```

The other way would be to filter your select query i-e hide all those fields which aren't expire;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `yourTable` WHERE `expiration` >= NOW();";
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `crontab`.

Using it, you will be able to schedule scripts to run in determinate times, for example:

Run `deleteExpiredRows.php` every `5 minutes`
Run `updateOnlineUsers.php` every `2 hours`

Cron is very easy to use. Check this [quick reference guide](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

#### Setting up crontabs at your web hosting:

`/path/to/hosting/php /home/user/public_html/script.php`

Path to php may vary, so contact your hosting to get this information. More information about crontab can be found here at stackoverflow.
Note: you might want to check if your web hosting service supports crontab.

After this is done, you just need to create your PHP script to delete every row older than current time.